# Supported animations when exporting in HTML

Tags: html, animation, export, keynote

I am looking for the list of the animations which are supported on Keynote (currently 6.6.2) when exporting on HTML.

Unsupported animations are currently replaced by the dissolve animation.

If nobody has it, then I am going to take some time to check for it by myself and post your the list here, hoping it will be useful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I answer this with the French names only...
If you need to find which name correspond to what, here is an example website I made to answer this: http://animation.keynote.tulleb.com/

---

List of **transitions** which **does** supports the HTML export:

- Corde à linge
- Dépôt
- Dévoilement
- Dissolution
- Fondu couleur
- Glissement
- Glissé entrant
- Permuter
- Quadrillage
- Métamorphose (one of the best imo)
- Chute en avant
- Cube
- Echange
- Echelle
- Jaillissement
- Mosaïque
- Pivotement
- Portail
- Porte à tambour
- Reflet
- Retournement
- Tournoiement
- Volets
- Apparition subite
- Cube (another one)
- Glissement (another one)
- Perspective
- Renvers
- Rotation d'objet
- Zoom avant
- Balançoire

List of **transitions** which **doesn't** support the HTML export:

- Balayage
- Confettis
- Goutte d'eau
- Iris
- Affaissement
- Page tournée
- Plans de couleur
- Torsion
- Chatoiement
- Scintillement

---

List of **animations** which **does** supports the HTML export:

- Apparition
- Compression
- Dépôt
- Dérive
- Dérive et mise à l'échelle
- Dissolution
- Glissé entrant
- Machine à écrire (supported but not optimized)
- Passage vers l'intérieur
- Apparition subite
- Cube
- Gros plan
- Jaillissement
- Mise à l'échelle
- Orbite
- Pivotement
- Retournement
- Torsion et mise à l'échelle
- Toupie
- Tournoiement
- Volets
- Comète
- Dérapage
- Flashes
- Goutte
- Halo
- Rebond

List of **animations** which **doesn't** support the HTML export:

- Balayage
- Flou
- Fondu et échelle
- Iris
- Chatoiement
- Confettis
- Enclume
- Explosion
- Feu d'artifice
- Flamme
- Scintillement
- Tracer

---

Hope it will help!